# Understand the With-As commands when starting the Playwright

Tags: robotframework, playwright-python

I'm trying to integrate Playwright and RobotFW together after spending years working with Selenium + RobotFW.

My test case is very simple:

```
TEST_1 Check correctness of showing Login screen
    [Tags]   ui     automated
    Go to login screen normally
```

I defined the keyword as below:

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()

@keyword('Go to login screen normally')
def go_to_login_screen_normally():
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://my.page.com/login")
    print(page.title())
    browser.close()
```

But it always return the error `Event loop is closed`

However, this one works:

```
@keyword('Go to login screen normally')
def go_to_login_screen_normally():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("https://my.page.com/login")
        print(page.title())
        browser.close()
```

Means I have to put the `With` section into the function.

I tried to skip the `With-As` but it does not work as well.

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: If you are interested in playwright with robot framework than you should have a look at [browser library](https://robotframework-browser.org/)

Comment: @JiriJanous I want to use only Python. Browser library requires a lot of stuff like NodeJS... quite bulky